# Camunda: use callActivity without tenant from tenant specific bpm

Tags: camunda

We have a multi tenant application and some tenants need a data pre processing to modify incoming data from third party modules.
Therefore we use tenant specific bpm's like in the image below [tenant specific bpmn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAbOf.png)
There we need a callActivity to call an internal dataPreProcess which have no tenant defined.
The problem is, how i can set the tenant id to 'no tenant' so that the multi-tenant specific workflow is called?

Information:
We don't have a chance to deploy the internal data pre process as a tenant specific bpm, because the tenants are dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After i post the question it was so easy....

In the groovy script 'LF011' set a variable like

execution.setVariable('tenant', null)

So in the callActivity you can use '${tenant}' as the Tenant id, that's it....

Comment: cool. Please remember to accept your own answer to indicate this question closed. Thanks!